# How to index a 1 billion row CSV file with elastic search?

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, bigdata, nest, bulkinsert

Imagine you had a large CSV file - let's say 1 billion rows.

You want each row in the file to become a document in elastic search.

You can't load the file into memory - it's too large so has to be streamed or chunked.

The time taken is not a problem. The priority is making sure ALL data gets indexed, with no missing data.

What do you think of this approach:

**Part 1: Prepare the data**

- Loop over the CSV file in batches of 1k rows
- For each batch, transform the rows into JSON and save them into a smaller file
- You now have 1m files, each with 1000 lines of nice JSON
- The filenames should be incrementing IDs. For example, running from 1.json to 1000000.json

**Part 2: Upload the data**

- Start looping over each JSON file and reading it into memory
- Use the bulk API to upload 1k documents at a time
- Record the success/failure of the upload in a result array
- Loop over the result array and if any upload failed, retry

Comment: It's a good start! Try it with 100K rows first and see what happens.

Comment: You can also use logstash to do that, it will take care of everything you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps you've mentioned above looks good. A couple of other things which will make sure ES does not get under load:

- From what I've experienced, you can increase the bulk request size to a greater value as well, say somewhere in the range 4k-7k (start with 7k and if it causes pain, experiment with smaller batches but going lower than 4k probably might not be needed).
- Ensure the value of `refresh_interval` is set to a very great value. This will ensure that the documents are not indexed very frequently. IMO the default value will also do. Read more [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/indices-refresh.html#refresh-api-desc).

As the above comment suggests, it'd be better if you start with a smaller batch of data. Of-course, if you use constants instead of hardcoding the values, your task just got easier.

Comment: @TomDane did you execute it? Any blockers you faced worth sharing?